# Pointer type compile-time error in GSL ODE solution

Tags: c++, pointers, gsl, ode

I'm working with the code on the GSL examples page to try to solve a system of four differential equations. I've been wrestling with passing five parameters to the ODE system, and have arrived at one final (I hope!) compile-time error. A snippet follows, giving me the error

```
114:57: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)(double, const double*, 
double*, double**, void*)’ to ‘int (*)(double, const double*, double*, 
double*, void*)’ [-fpermissive]
```

which corresponds to the line starting with `gsl_odeiv2_system`:

```
int main()
{
  double t = 0.0;
  double y[4] = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
  int i, s;

  struct pendula_params * info;
  info->m2 = 1.0;
  info->m1 = 1.0;
  info->l1 = 1.0;
  info->l2 = 1.0;
  info->g  = 1.0;

  gsl_odeiv2_system sys = { pendula, jacobian, 4, &info };

  gsl_odeiv2_driver *d =
    gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys, gsl_odeiv2_step_msadams,
                                   1e-3, 1e-8, 1e-8);
```

Any thoughts on what might be going on?

Many thanks,

Mark C.

Comment: How is your struct `pendula_params` defined?

Comment: Another issue: You are accessing the uninitialized pointer `info`. It should probably not be a pointer in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. Figured that out when it seg-fault'ed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what the error is by comparing the two function types that appear in the error message.

The [gsl_odeiv2_system](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Defining-the-ODE-System.html) structure expects the `jacobian` member to be a pointer to a function that takes a `double*` as the fourth parameter. But your `jacobian` function takes a `double**` as the fourth parameter, which makes it incompatible.

Comment: How'd you know it was `jacobian` and not `pendula`? Seems to work for me!

Comment: @MarkC. Because `jacobian` member of `gsl_odeiv2_system` takes 5 parameters, which matches the function types in the error message.